# Can't get image url after upload a file to Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage, react-state

I need some help. I have the following code example. I set the current image url to state, but I get it after a few renderings, so once I call it in onRequestHandler, I don't get it right after. Is there any way I can wait for him to get it?

```
const Component= () => {
const [url, setUrl] = useState('');

const uploadFile = async (file) => {
    if (!file) {
        return;
    }

    const storageRef = ref(storage, `/documents/${file.name}`);
    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);
    
    uploadTask.on('state_changed', (snapshot) => {
        const prog = Math.round((snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100);
        setProgress(prog);
    },
        (err) => console.log(err),
        () => {
            getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref)
                // .then((url) => console.log(url));
                .then((url) => setUrl(prevState => url));
            }
    );
       }
    
const onRequestHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    uploadFile('giving the file from form');
   // I need the image url here to set it to the current user.
}


return ({ <form onSubmit={onRequestHandler}> </form> })
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're calling `getDownloadURL` in the client-side JavaScript ode, it only executes after the page has loaded. At that point there is no way to wait for an asynchronous operation to complete before rendering the page to your user.

Your rendering code will have to handle the case where the image URL isn't available yet, typically by not rendering the image in that case, or by rendering a placeholder image URL. Then when you call `setUrl`, the page will rerender and you can show the correct image URL.

Answer (score 0):

**you have to use useEffect Hook beacause this url will be working in asynchronously**
*Here is my code : *

```js
  const [imageUpload, setImageUpload] = React.useState(null); // image selecting state
  const [image, setImage] = React.useState(""); //url setting state
  
  const storage = getStorage();

  useEffect(() => {
    // declare the data getImage function
    const getImage = async () => {
      const ImageURL = await getDownloadURL(ref(storage, `${imageUpload.name}`));
      setImage(ImageURL);
    }
    // call the function
    getImage()
    console.log(image)
  }, [imageUpload])
  
  const uploadImage = () => {
    if (imageUpload == null) return;  
    const storageRef = ref(storage, `${imageUpload.name}`);
    uploadBytes(storageRef, imageUpload).then((snapshot) => {
      console.log("Uploaded image");
    });
  };
```

```js
  const [image, setImage] = useState(""); //url selected
  
  const storage = getStorage();

  useEffect(() => {
    // declare the data getImage function
    const getImage = async () => {
      const ImageURL = await getDownloadURL(ref(storage, `${imageUpload.name}`));
      setImage(ImageURL);
    }
    // call the function
    getImage()
    console.log(image)
  }, [imageUpload])
```